# Community URL No Longer Exists

Tags: community

I just setup a Community. When I go to the URL that was generated, I get "URL No Longer Exists"

What do I need to do?

Comment: Did you receive an email from Salesforce saying the domain had been registered?

Comment: It existed already. This is the second community.

Comment: Have you set the 2nd community as "active" yet in `Communities | All Communities > Manage > Administration > Settings`? Until you do, the link won't be accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not see the URL until you go and hit the publish button

[image]

Also preview the URL once and make sure you have right URL

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the issue, Community URL No Longer Exists, you have to re-publish the Communities on Sandbox (completed successfull).