# Why a Community in Sandbox shows only "URL No Longer Exists"?

Tags: community, lightning-community

I have a community in Production-Org up and running.

- It's a Lightning Community based on Napili-Template
- the Production Community URL is https://MYDOMAIN.force.com/Community/s/

Now I've spun a new Developer-Sandbox (no data) today.

- Name of my new Sandbox is "comm0922"
- The Sandbox has copied the Community to the new Sandbox
- The new Community is listet at All Communities on comm0922
- The new Community is editable with the Community Builder
- The new Community has it's own URL (different from Production-Org) https://0922comm-MYDOMAIN.cs89.force.com/Community/s/

But the Sandbox-Community-URL only shows this

[image]

**Question**

What are the exact steps I need to take on a blank new Developer Sandbox in order to see a working copy of my production community? Why I've getting the Aloha-style error, while this is a Lightning community?

**What have I done so far?**

- checked this [Community URL No Longer Exists](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141011/community-url-no-longer-exists)
- re-published Community on Sandbox (completed successfull)
- still "URL No Longer Exists"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It turned out, that waiting has helped.**

- I've tried it the first time after about 12 hours after the Sandbox has become available.
- Then I got the error.
- Then I republished.
- Still got the error.
- 3 more hours passed.
- **Now the error is gone - without having done anything else...**

Very strange behavior...

Comment: I can confirm this as well - despite the Community Builder stating community was published; it took another 45 minutes before the error went away